# Ruby math calculator program

Tags: ruby, user-input, gets

I wrote a program.

```
print "Radius = "
radius = gets.chomp

print "Height = "
height = gets.chomp

ans = (2 * 3.14 * (radius * radius)) + (2 * 3.14 * radius * height)
```

It won't work. This is the output in the terminal (`"11"` and `"10"` are what I put in as the radius/height of the cylinder):

```
Radius = 11
Height = 10
in `*': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
```

Please help.

Comment: " can't convert String into Integer " strongly suggests that **you** need to convert `radius` and `height` to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to `chomp` if you convert your input strings to integers using `to_i`. And there's a constant `PI` in `Math`.

```
print "Radius = "
radius = gets.to_i

print "Height = "
height = gets.to_i

ans = (2 * Math::PI * (radius * radius)) + (2 * Math::PI * radius * height)

puts "Answer: #{ans}"
```

also know as

```
ans = 2 * Math::PI * radius * (radius + height)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error causes as `radius` and `height` is taken as `String` from the terminal. Look below:

```
p "Radius = "
radius = gets.chomp
p radius.class
p "Height = "
height = gets.chomp
p radius.class
p ans = (2 * 3.14 * (radius * radius)) + (2 * 3.14 * radius * height)
```

***Output:***

```
"Radius = "
11
String
"Height = "
12
String
 `*': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
```

So 2 strings can't be multiplied.To make this workable,do:

```
p "Radius = "
radius = gets.chomp.to_i #// or gets.to_i
p "Height = "
height = gets.chomp.to_i #// or gets.to_i
p ans = (2 * 3.14 * (radius * radius)) + (2 * 3.14 * radius * height)
```

***Output:***

```
"Radius = "
12
"Height = "
11
1733.2800000000002
```